# Disabling RadioButtonList dynamically on code-behind

Tags: html, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have an .aspx page that works as a PopUp. Sometimes, one RadioButtonList on this PopUp must be enabled, sometimes not. Here is the control :

```
<acc:RadiobuttonList ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true">
  <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0" />
</acc:RadiobuttonList>
```

I tried two ways but none worked (even updating the UpdatePanel):

- `RadioButton1.Attributes.Add( "disabled", "disabled" );`
- `RadioButton1.Enabled = false;`

Only the RadioButtonList is having this behavior (there is another's controls in the page).

What is wrong?

Obs: I noticed that the 'SupportsDisabledAttribute' property of the control is 'false'. This can be influencing in the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works fine

```
RadioButton1.Enabled = false;
RadioButton1.Items[0].Enabled = false;
```

May I know why is the namespace as **acc** and not **asp**

Comment: Yes, this works fine. The problem was the name of the control in code-behind. Silly mistake.

I use <b> acc </b> to add functionalities to the default's .NET Web Controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try `RadioButton1.Items(0).Enabled = False`... 0 being the index of the button to disable